# Monitor how long per day or hour I'm close to my maximuim internet bandwith? So if it makes sense to buy an upgrade

Tags: networking, monitoring, internet, statistics

for quite some time I'm working at home now. Recently I questioned if my current internet connection is good enough for my activity on my laptop. For some activities I notice a high internet usage, but I want clear facts and not just a gut feeling.

So I wondered, if I can automatically monitor how many seconds/minutes... per day or hour I'm close to my internet connection limit. So I can get clue if an upgrade makes sense to speed up my activity.

Is there a tool for that? I looked at vnstat, but it's not what I'm looking for. Also I would need to look at Download and Upload separately.

Comment: Usually for such things, your router need to support SNMP so that the counters can be extracted, compared and graphed.

Comment: @Bib Thank for the hint. I didn't know about this. Sadly not available at my router.

Comment: If it's Linux based, you may be able to gain access and install the required code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349576/linux-retrieve-per-interface-sent-received-packet-counters-ethernet-ipv4-ipv) :

- you can read the amount of sent / received bytes from `/sys/class/net/<interface>/statistics/tx_bytes` and `/sys/class/net/<interface>/statistics/rx_bytes`
- retrieve values every n minutes and record them in a CSV file
- you may import data in your favorite spreadsheet program and compute anything you like